# Decorating Java 8 Files.lines() stream with filename

Tags: java, java-stream

`Files.lines()` returns a `Stream<String>` of each line in the file. What I want is a Stream of Map, with the key the line, and the value the filename. This must be an intermediate, not a terminal, result in a pipeline.

What is the best way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Nothing that works.

Comment: @ChrisJoslin that is not helpful. This site is run by people volunteering their time. You need to show an attempt.

Comment: Actually I don't need to show anything. And if it did it would not be helpful, because the ideas I came up with clearly did not work. How far this site has fallen from its early days.

Comment: In order to ask a high-quality question that gets upvotes, you [should show effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284599/5743988) in your question. Your proposed structure doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Why does every key have the same value? It also sounds like you need a stream of `Map.Entry` and not a stream of `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
final String fileName = ""; //File name
List<String> lines = new ArrayList(); //Get the lines
lines.stream()
.map(l -> {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(l, fileName);
    return map;
});
```

You can use Google [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s `ImmutableMap` class to create a map (for simplified version), e.g.

```
final String fileName = "";
List<String> lines = new ArrayList();
lines.stream()
.map(l -> ImmutableMap.of(l, fileName));
```

Comment: But wouldn't that load all the lines immediately? This must be done lazily.

Comment: No, it wouldn't `load` all the lines. All the `stream` functions are lazy and do not get evaluated until a `collect` is encountered. You can verify it by placing a `sysout` inside `map` function.

Comment: @ChrisJoslin, wanting a `Map` and wanting laziness are contradictory desires.  If you want laziness, you'll need something other than a map -- e.g. a list of pairs.

Comment: When you have lines = new ArrayList, I mean. If that is meant to be a stub for a real read, it's not lazy.

Comment: A `Map` has _all_ of the keys and all the values, all at once.  A Stream of Maps doesn't make sense for what you want -- you want a stream of map _entries_, or pairs, or whatever custom type you choose.

Comment: You don’t need an external library to get an immutable `Map` with a single mapping: `.stream().map(l-> Collections.singletonMap(l, fileName))`